# Seeking Suggestions to Resolve FireDAC ODBC Error in Delphi Service Application

Tags: sql-server, delphi, graphql, odbc, firedac

I’ve developed a service application in Delphi that handles GraphQL queries. The primary function of this application is to fetch data from a Microsoft SQL database and supply it to a Magento webshop.

The application works as expected for the most part. However, I occasionally encounter the following error:

> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hStmt

In an attempt to resolve this issue, I’ve implemented several changes based on solutions I found online:

```
Query1.Connection.FetchOptions.RowsetSize := -1;
// this did not help
 
Query1.ResourceOptions.CmdExecMode := amAsync; 
// this did not help; it resulted in an access violation error message!

Query1.ResourceOptions.CmdExecMode := amNonBlocking;
// this did not help

Query1.Connection.Params.Values['ODBCAdvanced'] := 'MARS_Connection=YES'; 
or
Query1.Connection.Params.Values['ODBCAdvanced'] := 'MARS=YES';
// this did not help
```

Unfortunately, none of these modifications have been successful in preventing the error message. I even introduced a delay after retrieving the results using Sleep(3000), but this too proved ineffective.

I’m reaching out to this community in the hope that someone might have encountered a similar issue and can provide some guidance or suggestions on how to fix this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you share a single connection for all requests, this might be a bad idea. Usually one does a connection pooling solution so you have at most one execution per connection at the same time

Comment: MARS support has been a thing since SQL Server 2005. Is it possible that somewhere in your software stack you have a really old version of SQL Server, the ODBC Driver for SQL Server (since you're using a bridging driver), or perhaps even FireDAC?

Comment: Using connection pooling is very simple in FireDAC and would require little changes to your application. Look at this example: https://blogs.embarcadero.com/using-firedac-connection-pooling-with-rad-server/

Comment: Thanks! I have changed my code in order to have a new connection for each query I run. using the pooling mechanism, and this seems to work...